# Fedora 20 guest shutdown does not close the VirtualBox window

Tags: virtualbox, fedora

I have a Fedora 20 guest OS in VirtualBox, and when I shut it down, it shows the usual shutdown screen, followed by "system halted".

Nothing else happens, the VirtualBox window does not close automatically as it does on other guest OS (CentOS 6, Windows XP).

Is it possible to make it close the window automatically?

Note: VirtualBox Guest Additions are installed on the guest.

Comment: seems like acpi_power_off is not being called. How are you shutting it down?

Comment: @ssnobody You just made me realize it only happens when I shut it down using `sudo halt`. Using the GUI, it does close the window! Is there any particular reason why?

Comment: `halt` halts the system but does not power it off unless you specify -p or --poweroff so this is expected behavior. You should be able to use `sudo poweroff` to shut it down and power if off though...

Comment: Interesting, but strangely enough, `sudo poweroff` just gets me a black screen. Also, `halt` does close the VirtualBox window in CentOS 6!?

Comment: You can also try `shutdown -h -t 0` to see if it powers off. One possibility to explain the difference between halt behaviors is that the halt script in Fedora 20 vs CentOS 6 may set INIT_HALT to different values. Another might be the acpi isn't working or is not supported in your Fedora 20 instance, though this is unlikely if you can get a proper poweroff from the GUI.